# How to get all objects stored inside proxy?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume that this is the proxy.

```
var target = {};
var p = new Proxy(target, {});
p.a = 1; 
p.b = 2;
```

I know I can access the objects via `console.log(p.a)` and `console.log(p.b)` but how do I programatically fetch all the objects stored?

Disclaimer: I'm a Javascript noob but I did read the documentation at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Examples but it wasn't really clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var target = {};
var p = new Proxy(target, {});
p.a = 1; 
p.b = 2;

console.log(p);
// {
//   "a": 1,
//   "b": 2
// }

console.log(Object.keys(p));
// ["a", "b"]


// only in ES6 and above:
console.log(Object.values(p));
// [1, 2]

// In older JS versions:
for(var key of Object.keys(p)) {
  console.log(p[key]);
}
// 1
// 2
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the `for .. in` loop

```
for (var property in p) {
    console.log(p[property]);
}
```

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in)

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky question because with a `Proxy` object you are in complete control of what property access does. In the MDN example you're actually adding a default response for all properties - so if a property isn't found in the object, `37` is returned. In that sense, the proxied object can be said to have an infinite number of properties.

You might try `Object.keys` or an enumeration via `for ... in`, but you might not get exactly what you want if the proxy `handler` does a lot.

In general, when working with `Proxy` I'd avoid thinking about "all the properties".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```js
const example = {
Name: "What is your Name",  Age: 0 };

const Don = {
  Name : "Don Quixote",  Age: 25
};
const handler = {
  getPrototypeOf(target) {
    return Don;
  }
};
const myproxy = new Proxy(example, handler);
var a = Object.getPrototypeOf(myproxy);
for (var i in a) 
{
   console.log(i + ":" +  a[i] );
}
```